# What subjects would you like to see investigated and reported on in the world of sound for picture?

Tags: production-mixing, re-recording

I am starting a new position as an editor for an industry publication (CAS Quarterly) that focuses on sound for picture. I am starving for suggestions on what aspects of audio post or audio production people would like to see investigated and discussed.  Our readership includes, foley, ADR, re-recording, and production mixers. Any ideas on subjects we should explore?

Comment: Good grief who flagged to close this?

Answer (score 3):

collaboration always makes for better stories than technique IMO.

So stories about working with directors, stories about working with actors, stories about working with the final mix team, etc.

I also like case studies and how *not* to do it stories.  :)

Answer (score 3):

Rock on, Karol!

I'm always interested in the aesthetic side; the decision making process as it relates to the story. Why folks make the choices they do, how they perceive the implications of those choices in relation to the overall narrative, and whether or not it had the intended effect.

Answer (score 2):

Every film I have ever been a part of has one shared element: WORKFLOW. Each sound crew approaches it differently, and does each picture department and each mixing stage. How they work together is critical and affects the entire process, from the first day of turnover to the final day of M&E.

There have been published discussions on this topic but I don't think you can ever have enough documented examples of which methods have proved successful (or unsuccessful), why, how they could have been improved, etc. Given the many ways of working together as a group, from shared office space to satellite studios (local or global), having a well thought-out workflow in place from day 1 will have a major impact on how each member of the group spends his/her time, how much productivity is wasted doing repetitive tasks, and so on. And how will the various groups communicate and collaborate with each other? Via a cloud-based setting like Dropbox or Box.net? Does Google enter the picture? What about shared Soundminer databases? How is the picture department turning over dailies, AAFs and picture files? Is it as efficient as possible, without hours of wasted time making different versions and file types for different departments?

So, I'd like to see more of that!

Answer (score 1):

The fundamentals have been covered. How about, every now and again, a deep technical dissection of a single sound effect? Also some of the finer storytelling aspects wouldn't go wrong at all (Ondaatje's "The Conversations" did this very well). Maybe an occasional horror story from the dub stage, if anyone dares? Fewer stories about how director X works with sound, those seem to be left right and centre..

Answer (score 0):

Good suggestions already. I'd also love to read some articles or comparisons of technique and workflow in less documented industries - China, Japan, Middle East etc.